# problem in XML parser when a extra quote

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have written a xml parser which successfully parses a xml file which is given as input.But sometime the input file that is given to may parser has double quote in a text property because of which my parser crashes.

Eg

```
<tag  myprop=" this has a extra quote here like " some times" >  </tag>
```

I know the tag that may /may not have the extra quote.I use a dom parser.

How can i handle this situation?

Comment: I don't think writing your own XML parser is a good idea, especially since you apparently don't even understand the basics of XML yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use an XML parser until you have actual XML.  What you currently have is invalid (ie not XML).  You should escape the quote-mark inside the attribute beforehand.

The escaped code would look like:

```
<tag  myprop=" this has a extra quote here like &quot; some times" >  </tag>
```

As to why your parser crashes, well there are [dozens of XML libraries](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java%20xml%20parser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in existence - have you looked at any of those?  I would personally expect to receive a [ParseException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I think it's just invalid XML and so your parser should fail gracefully (rather than crashing) but I don't think it should successfully parse such a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. That is not a valid XML, so the DOM parser will fail to parse.

Answer (score 0):

see XML 1.0 specification, section 2.4:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#attdecls

> To allow attribute values to contain both single and double quotes,
>   the apostrophe or single-quote character (') may be represented as "
>   &apos ; ", and the double-quote character (") as "&quot ;"."

so, since it's not valid XML your parser shouldn't be trying to handle the invalid value, it just needs to give an error.